# How to define look up array for the VBA's Find Function

Tags: excel, vba

The Line of Code that is giving me an "Application Defined or Object Defined error" is `With Workbooks("Master Permitting-Test Sheet Copy Code").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A5", Range("A5").End(xlDown))`

```
  Sub Copy_Code()

Dim FileLocation As String
Dim Old_Workbook As Workbook
Dim New_Workbook As Workbook
Dim New_Job_Range As Range
Dim Old_Job_Name As String



Dim n As Integer
Dim Last_Old_Job As Integer


'gets input from user for file string name
FileLocation = Application.GetOpenFilename

'opens last weeks file and sets WB object for new workbook
Set Old_Workbook = Application.Workbooks.Open(FileLocation)
Set New_Workbook = Workbooks("Master Permitting-Test Sheet Copy Code")


'Find the last old job name in the old workbook
Last_Old_Job = Old_Workbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A5", Range("A5").End(xlDown)).Count


'Establish loop from the first old job to the last old job
For n = 1 To Last_Old_Job

'defines old job name, Starts in cell A5 and steps rows by 1 each time the loop is completed
Old_Job_Name = Old_Workbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A5").Offset(n - 1, 0).Value



 'The Array to Find the matching Old_Job_Name  
    With Workbooks("Master Permitting-Test Sheet Copy Code").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A5", Range("A5").End(xlDown))

'Sets the New_Job_Range equal to the cell where the old job matchs the new job
Set New_Job_Range = .Find(Old_Job_Name, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)

    'If New_Job_Range is not nothing (as in a match has been found) then offset the column by 3 on the old workbook and paste that data
    'offset 3 columns from the New_Job_Range
    If Not New_Job_Range Is Nothing Then
        Old_Job_Name = Old_Workbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A5").Offset(n - 1, 3).Copy
        New_Job_Range.Offset(0, 3).Paste


        End If

    End With

Next n

End Sub
```

Comment: Use one loop (against the old_workbook), and `Find` or `Match` in the new workbook.

Comment: If it goes straight to `next nn`, you are bypassing the `end if` I don't see a reason for the `else` statement. After `end if` use `next nn`. The error is confusing, I believe it is because the `if` statement has not been completed. If you do want to exit a loop, you can use `exit for`, but you still need to complete the `if..end if ` statement

Comment: Using proper indentation will allow you to see your nested blocks. If you don't know what nested blocks of code are, then that is your problem. Use this tool to automatically indent your code: https://rubberduckvba.com/

Comment: @BigBen Thank you for your suggestion to use 1 loop and find in the new workbook. I am now wondering how to define look up array for the find feature? I can get the paste location from offsetting the "find" return value. I have change the above code to reflect the changes I made